# Cell Reusability Issue

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a TableView in my app. Its purpose is to get feed from API and display it in cells (excatly like facebook). My cells have Dynamic height depending on the text and image. in the post
The problem is that when I give a static cell Identifier, the height of each cell mix up, If no it works but I get a warning. And I am afraid not to use cell Identifier and the memory usage goes high.

Also i have another question. Lets say I gave a button in each cell that is White by default and if pressed it becomes green. If i press on a button of a cell and the button becomes green, then I scroll down then scroll up to the cell, the button returns to white again. Any Idea why?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: any code provided would be much appreciated!

Comment: For your problem with button color, I think that you have to set in your datasource a state for each cell, and if the cell has been pressed for example you set the state to `true` because when your cells are reused, they are reset to their default state. Do you understand ?

Comment: You need to update your question with relevant code and specific details about any errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution of your second problem:**

Give button tag value in the cellForRowIndexpath method:`button.tag=indexPath.row;`

In your view did load:

```
   BOOL tapped =NO;
```

then in your button action method:

```
-(IBAction)buttonClick:(id)sender{

 if(sender.tag==0){

       button.backgroundColor= tapped ? [UIColor whiteColor]:[UIColor greenColor];
       tapped = !tapped;
 }
}
```

**OR do like this**

```
-(void)aMethod:(id)sender
{

       UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;

   if ([button.backgroundColor isEqual:[UIColor greenColor]]) {
         button.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
   }
   else{
         button.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
   }
}
```

Comment: thanks! that's excatly what I needed! I have an NSObject for each cellView and defined a bool inside it to know it it is clicked or not. the click alters the bool and according to the bool I draw the button. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to calculate the height for each and provide it accordingly in

```
- tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:
```

on a per-indexPath basis, and the cell will resize accordingly on dequeueing.

[Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:)

As for your second question, you will need to keep a model that maintains state for each indexPath, since the cell is reused. In this case, an array with the state of each button on each cell is appropriate, and you can check the array as the cell gets dequeued.

Comment: I do calculate it in the HeightForRowAtIndexPath, but if i use a cell Identifier views mix up